# How do I run http/3 with Express?

Tags: node.js, npm, quic, http3

For experimental purposes, I want to try, but HTTP-over-QUIC seems to be unavailable in Node.js. The [QUIC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quic) itself is available.

Comment: since QUIC and HTTP/3 is quite new, the NodeJS implementation is currently on progress. take a look to [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/38478).

Comment: Express would support HTTP/3 if NodeJS have this feature. take a look to [this issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4693).

Comment: It's important to note that express actually doesn't support http/2 even though Node supports it. According to [this issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/5061) (which then references [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/29829)), they've held off on it due to incompatibility between the Node APIs of http/2 and http/1.x.  As long as http/3 support is implemented with compatibility with http/1.x, I bet it could be compatible out of the box.

Comment: At the moment express doesn't support http/2, so good luck with http/3